# add some control inside ngfor angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

for example i have a ngfor

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let setting of settings | trackBy: trackById">
              <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
              <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                <button mat-menu-item>{{ setting.value.caption }}</button>
              </mat-menu>
</ng-container>
```

it will show a list of a button from how many value inside the ngfor settings.

and now i want to add some checkbox for example but only with button number 1.

it should be like this more less.

```
<button> 
<button><checkbox>
<button>
```

any idea how to achieve like these?

sorry need to update my question.
how about if i want to achieve like this

```
<button>
<button>
<checklist>
<button>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce 'first as' into your ngFor and add a container to check if it's the first element in iteration:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let setting of settings; first as isFirst; trackBy: trackById">
    (...code...)
    <button...></button>
    <ng-container *ngIf="isFirst">
        <checkbox...></checkbox>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

If by 'number 1' you indeed mean at position index==1, then use:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let setting of settings; let i = index; trackBy: trackById">
    (...code...)
    <button...></button>
    <ng-container *ngIf="i == 1">
        <checkbox...></checkbox>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

If you want to display checkbox for element at position 2 and button for every other:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="i == 2">
    <checkbox...></checkbox>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="i != 2">
    <button...></button>
</ng-container>
```

or, shorter:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="i == 2; else showButton">
    <checkbox...></checkbox>
</ng-container>
<ng-container #showButton">
    <button...></button>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: is it working only for the first element? how about if i want to take 3 element from iteration?

Comment: 'isFirst' (or however you call it, just make sure it's 'first as' before it) will point to item at position [0], and if you use i = index version, you can check for any value of i.

Comment: how about if i want to skip the button in second or whatever iteration and change with checkbox? so like.. button button checkbox button in vertical way.

Comment: I edited the answer with new examples, better to put code there than in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index to get the current index,

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let setting of settings | trackBy: trackById; let idx = index">
              <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
              <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                <button mat-menu-item>{{ setting.value.caption }}</button>
                <checkbox *ngIf="idx === 1" />
              </mat-menu>
</ng-container>
```